# Preciso retornar o resultado do parseamento da requisição XHR ao escopo da Classe

Tags: javascript

```
class AjaxHelper {

    constructor( service, requestType, bol ) {

        this._uri = service;
        this._requestType = requestType;
        this._async = bol;
        this._domain = 'https://private-4e803-salarycalculatorapi.apiary-mock.com';
        this._url = this._domain + '' + this._uri;

        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
        xhr.open(this._requestType, this._url, this._async)
        xhr.send();                  

        function transferComplete(event) {
            var data = JSON.parse(event.target.responseText);
            return data;
        }

        console.log(data);

    }

    get url() {
        return this._url;
    }

}
```

> Preciso retornar o resultado do parceamento JSON da requisição XHR ao escopo da Classe, porém não consigo compreender como as funções passadas no objeto da requisição  funcionam. VAR DATA SÓ EXISTE DENTRO DE SEU ESCOPO.

```
    <script src="app/helpers/AjaxHelper.js"></script>
    <script>

        var myresource = new AjaxHelper('/inss','GET', true);
        myresource.data;

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que a chamada ajax é assíncrona, logo não tem como saber quando vai realmente executar e consequentemente retornar o valor. E na linha em que normalmente iria tentar obter o valor, a seguir a `new AjaxHelper(...);`, o valor ainda não está disponível.

Em vez disso pode passar um [*callback*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) ao construtor da sua classe, com o código que pretende executar na resposta. Esse *callback* tem depois de ser chamado no `transferComplete`:

```
class AjaxHelper {

    constructor( service, requestType, bol, callback /*callback agora aqui*/ ) {

        this._uri = service;
        this._requestType = requestType;
        this._async = bol;
        this._domain = 'https://private-4e803-salarycalculatorapi.apiary-mock.com';
        this._url = this._domain + '' + this._uri;
        this.callback = callback; //guarda o callback na classe

        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
        xhr.open(this._requestType, this._url, this._async)
        xhr.send();                  

        function transferComplete(event) {
            var data = JSON.parse(event.target.responseText);
            callback(data); //callback chamado aqui com os dados da resposta
        }

        console.log(data);

    }

    get url() {
        return this._url;
    }

}
```

E agora chama assim:

```
<script>
    //callback recebe os dados da resposta como parâmetro 
    new AjaxHelper('/inss','GET', true, (dados) => { 
        //aqui usa os dados que são a resposta do ajax
        console.log(dados);
    });

</script>
```